# How to set slide number in generated slide using python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am generating new slides using python pptx and I see no way to update the slide number. I have set the footer in master layout but when I try to read the shapes, I don't see that component over there.

My code:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('sample_ppt.pptx')
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[14]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)

for shape in slide.shapes:
    print(shape.name)
prs.save('hh.pptx')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a common confusion, possibly because the way PowerPoint handles footers is, well, confusing :)

The short answer is that you need to put a plain-textbox shape (not a footer placeholder) on the master slide, and insert into that textbox a slide-number *field*, using Insert > Slide Number from the menu. On the master, it will appear something like `<#>`, but on the slide that inherits from that master, it will appear as the slide number.

Comment: So if I wanna do this with python-pptx, I need to create text-holder and insert page number by myself?

Comment: Adding fields (like the slide-number field) isn't supported yet by the API in `python-pptx`. Most folks add that to the master of their starting template. If you need to retroactively add this to a set of existing presentations you'd need to pursue modifying the XML of a text-box paragraph. It looks like the `a:t` element is wrapped with an `a:fld` element with some simple attributes.

Comment: Thanks! @scanny, I add a textbox to the corner of a slide, then put the index number into it :-)